extract individual files from concatenated gzipped files
I know that we can easily concatenate multiple gzipped files to create one big (valid) gzip file that contains all the data:
gzip -c A > A.gz
gzip -c B > B.gz
cat A.gz B.gz > AB.gz

If I then unzip the resulting AB.gz, I get the content of both A and B:
cat A B > ab
gzip -dc AB.gz > AB
diff ab AB

However, I would like to restore the input files individually.
Now gzip(1) is rather explicit:

If you wish to create a single archive file with multiple members so that members can later be extracted independently, use an archiver such as tar or zip. [...] gzip is designed as a complement to tar, not as a replacement.

Unfortunately, I cannot really use tar as an intermediate layer (for $reasons).
Since gzip stores metainformation within the gz file (the original filename) and I can concatenate individual gz-files, i figure that there must be some chunk marker, so gzip knows that it needs to reset.
But: how?
There's a --name flag to restore the a (single) member by its original name, but with multi-member gzip-files, it will just use the name of the first member to restore the concatenated content:
gzip -kdN AB.gz

If this is not possible with the gzip cmdline tool, a Python solution would be fine as well...

Brief experimentation suggests you can look for 1f 8b 08 00

well 0x1F8B is the magic number, and 0x08 is (afaik) the only supported compression method (DEFLATE). but  the 4th byte is a flag-field that can hold various values, so it will not be 0x00 in the general case (esp it will be non-zero if the gzfile includes the original filename). more important however: is there some guarantee that the compressed data will not contain the magic sequence?

I don't think so. I experimented for a bit and did not see any false positives, but I haven't examined the spec.

Well, if you can't use tar, then you will have to recreate it. You could prefix each file with a length, for example.

No, not with the command-line tool. Searching for gzip headers can result in false-positives. Nothing prevents, e.g., 1f 8b 08 from appearing in compressed data. In fact it very likely will, more than once, in just 100 MB of compressed data.
The Python modules do not provide a means to recover the name from the gzip header. You would need to parse each gzip header yourself, and then use zlib.decompressobj() on the raw deflate data after each gzip header, along with zlib.crc32() to compute the CRC-32 of the uncompressed data to compare with the trailer. deflate streams are self-terminating. See RFC 1952 for details on the gzip header and trailer.
As you have noted, this is not the intended use of the gzip format.

I started to write a tool to make this easier to do, but then I came across another question https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/687900/un-concatenate-gzipped-file which contains two solutions (a perl script and a rust cli) that do exactly what you want.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
